# Pagination on MongoDb Views

Tags: mongodb

How to use limit and offset on MongoDB Views dynamically?

```
db.anonymous.aggregate()
      //.match(qb.where("status").eq("A"))
      //.project("gender _id")
      //.unwind("$arrayField")
      //.group({ _id: "", count: { $sum: 1 } })
      //.sort("-count")
      .limit(100)
      .offset(100)
      .saveAsView("anonymous_view",{dropIfExists:false})
```

I want to send the limit and offset value to the above query.

Regards
Pavan